# Does custom pagination in Laravel 5.6 still have a bug?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using LengthAwarePaginator class to "transform" collection into the paginator object. Everything works like a charm, but I need necessarily to change pagination page name. When i use setPageName() method- the page name inside url changes from default "page" to whatever I need to, but pagination links are not working at all- by clicking, the next page contents don't appear, even the url has its custom page name for pagination.

I read everywhere that this was bug before, but now its claimed it is fixed- although it gives the same bug as before this Laravel fix somewhere at v. 5.0.

PS: I need to do this by setPageName method.

PS2: If this is a bug again, why to not solve it if we found out.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
$currentPage=LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage()-1;
perPage=1;
    // $items is collection variable
$currentPageBlogResults = $items->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();

$items= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageBlogResults, count($items), $perPage);
$items->setPageName('special');
$items->setPath('main-category');
```

**View**

```
@foreach($items as $items)
.....
@endforeach    
{{$items->links()}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug (I guess). You're resolving current page with `LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage()` but it has own page name (defaults to "page"). You have two options:

```
$currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage('special') - 1;
```

or

```
LengthAwarePaginator::currentPageResolver(function () {
    return 'special';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip Mustafa! Visibly, the URL si changing to 'special', even the page is displaying proper results of pagination, but sadly- the links for the pagination- its link always stays at number one page and behaves like page 1 was chosen, even when you are at page 2 or 3 or 4 and displaying proper items....what you think? Thank you

Comment: [https://paste.laravel.io/1d6fcf73-64d8-4695-b6b4-50999383d797](https://paste.laravel.io/1d6fcf73-64d8-4695-b6b4-50999383d797) I just tried dirty quick and I couldn't see a problem. There should be another problem.

Comment: like this: https://paste.laravel.io/663cd4dc-6219-4e54-b93c-14ad67df496f